# Wordpress comment form validation error tooltip

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

if someone can tell me where this black tooltip (see on the enclosed picture) comes from when someone let the comment form empty (error case)...

[image]

I use TwentyEleven child theme, my WP has the latest version.

Before, WP redirected the page to an ugly empty error page what i customized via my functions.php :

```
// create comments error page
add_filter('wp_die_handler', 'get_my_custom_die_handler');

function get_my_custom_die_handler() {
    return 'my_custom_die_handler';
}

function my_custom_die_handler($message, $title='', $args=array()) {
    $errorTemplate = get_theme_root().'/'.get_template().'/commenterror.php';

    if(!is_admin() && file_exists($errorTemplate)) {
        $defaults = array( 'response' => 500 );
        $r = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);
        $have_gettext = function_exists('__');

        if ( function_exists( 'is_wp_error' ) && is_wp_error( $message ) ) {
            if ( empty( $title ) ) {
                $error_data = $message->get_error_data();
                if ( is_array( $error_data ) && isset( $error_data['title'] ) )
                $title = $error_data['title'];
            }
            $errors = $message->get_error_messages();
            switch ( count( $errors ) ) :
                case 0 :
                    $message = '';
                    break;
                case 1 :
                    $message = "<p>{$errors[0]}</p>";
                    break;
                default :
                    $message = "<ul>\n\t\t<li>" . join( "</li>\n\t\t<li>", $errors ) . "</li>\n\t</ul>";
                    break;
            endswitch;
        } elseif ( is_string( $message ) ) {
            $message = "<p>$message</p>";
        }

        if ( isset( $r['back_link'] ) && $r['back_link'] ) {
            $back_text = $have_gettext? __('&laquo; Back') : '&laquo; Back';
            $message .= "\n<p><a href='javascript:history.back()'>$back_text</a></p>";
        }

        if ( empty($title) ) $title = $have_gettext ? __('WordPress &rsaquo; Error') : 'WordPress &rsaquo; Error';

        require_once($errorTemplate);
        die();
    } else {
        _default_wp_die_handler($message, $title, $args);
    }
}
```

My commenterror.php :

```
get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary">
    <div id="errorcontent" role="main">
        <div id="errormessage" class="entry-content">
        <?php echo $message; ?>
        <?php if(wp_get_referer()){ ?><a href="<?php echo wp_get_referer(); ?>" title="Back to original page">Back to original page &rarr;</a><?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally i prefer this new (?) tooltip but it shows a message in French, however my blog (this one) is in English... certainly i let somewhere a sentence from a previous theme but i can not find the its place/its file...